# Hover effect in CSS3

Tags: css

I was working on a small JSfiddle which i have almost completed , [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/tgcuukop/4/) it has a glitch though , if you notice there are 2 hover effects , Look below :

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 34px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 34px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: -5px 34px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
img:hover {
    top: -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

and the 2nd hover effect here

```
.fancyborder {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all .4s ease-out 0s;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #444;
}
.fancyborder:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #65d125;
}
```

this works perfectly fine . One problem though is that want the effect to take place as soon as i hover the entire .col-md-3 div i.e. i  want both the :hover effects to fire as soon as i hover over the div.

The seemingly obvious solution : Now the seemingly obvious solution might be to do this

```
.col-md-3 {
    top: -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom: 5px solid #65d125;
}
```

The problem with this is obvious , this will apply the shadow property , the top:-15px and border-bottom to col-md-3 rather than img and span tags respectively .

Is there any complex CSS selection here that i can apply or some intelligent HTML i can write that will acheive what i want to . I know i am missing something really tiny here , but i have't been able to spot what it is .

Please guide me . you help will be appreciated.

Thank you .

Gautam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want both the :hover effects to fire as soon as i hover over the
>   `<div class="col-md-3 ">`

Then you could use `:hover` pseudo-class on `.col-md-3` at first and target the two other elements as follows:

```css
.down-border:hover img {
    top: -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.down-border:hover .fancyborder {
    border-bottom:5px solid #65d125;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 down-border">
```

**Note:** I've used `.down-border` selector instead of `.col-md-3` in order to select the div element because using `.col-md-3` may affect the other columns.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tgcuukop/5/)**

Comment: Thanks my friend , your explanation was elaborate .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the hover to the parent:

```
.col-md-3:hover img {
    top: -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.col-md-3:hover .fancyborder {
    border-bottom:5px solid #65d125;
}
```

Comment: Did't realise i could make a selection like that , well that was the "tiny" part that i was missing Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/tgcuukop/7/)

Change in the CSS:

```
.col-md-3:hover .fancyborder {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #65d125;
}


.col-md-3:hover img {
    top: -15px;
    /*background-color: red;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply your style like below.

```
 .col-md-3:hover img{
    top: -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   box-shadow: -5px 44px 37px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }

 .col-md-3:hover .fancyborder {
    border-bottom:5px solid #65d125;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/tgcuukop/9/)